# Search function error: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I get data from Marvel API and the data is displayed perfectly.
However, when I try to implement search function, I get this 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined at displayData' error.
Here is the code:

```
const apiUrl = ... ;

let data = [];

const searchBar = document.querySelector("#searchbar");
searchBar.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  const filter = data.data.results.filter((character) =>
    character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
  );
  displayData(filter);
});

async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
  data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  displayData(data);

  const characters = data.data.results;
  console.log(characters);
}

const displayData = (data) => {
  const characters = data.data.results;
  console.log(characters);
  for (character of characters) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += `
        <div class="character">
          <h1>${character.name}</h1>
          <a href="${character.urls[0].url}" target="_blank">
            <img src="${character.thumbnail.path}.${character.thumbnail.extension}" alt="${character.name}" height="100" class="image" />
          </a>
        </div>
    `;
  }
};
```

These console.log show that I get the data that I want, there is no error until I try to search and then it shows me that the error is on line 26 which is 'const characters = data.data.results;' in displayData function. Any help?

Comment: `displayData(filter);` in line 7 does return data.data

Comment: Can you share the output of `console.log(data)`?

Comment: This is the output of console.log(data): http://prntscr.com/uchuqg

Comment: Seems like a scoping issue with `let data = []`. When is `getData()` invoked?

Comment: getData() is invoked at the end of the file...

Comment: I suggest you produce a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `displayData(data)` from searchbar event listener, you are passing only a filtered array (without data property), and parameter name `data` is shadowing global `data` variable, but when you call `displayData` from `getData` function, you are passing the whole `data` object.

You can try changing the parameter passed to `displayData` function, and change a call to it from `getData` function:

```
const apiUrl = ... ;

let data = [];

const searchBar = document.querySelector("#searchbar");
searchBar.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  const filter = data.data.results.filter((character) =>
    character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
  );
  displayData(filter);
});

async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
  data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  displayData(data.data.results);

  const characters = data.data.results;
  console.log(characters);
}

const displayData = (characters) => {
  let filteredHTML = '';
  for (character of characters) {
    filteredHTML += `
        <div class="character">
          <h1>${character.name}</h1>
          <a href="${character.urls[0].url}" target="_blank">
            <img src="${character.thumbnail.path}.${character.thumbnail.extension}" alt="${character.name}" height="100" class="image" />
          </a>
        </div>
    `;
  };
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = filteredHTML;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, now there is no error in the console and search is working in the console, but I still see all characters displayed on the screen, nothing changes when I type

Comment: It seems that you are always appending the `output` element `innerHTML` property. So it seems that every call to `displayData` is adding additional content to `output`, without actually resetting it.

Comment: I edited my answer with changing the way `displayData` content is generated.